# Не корректно работает галерея изображений

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel

Добрый день не корректно работает слайдер http://lp.nartov.com.ua/

При переключении изображений (с маленького на большое) на первых четырех объектах все переключается, на остальных перестает работать, когда было 3 объекта , переключались только первых 2, добавляю следующие те которые были последними начинают работать, новые перестают.

Как я понял основному изображению перестает переключаться класс active. Как исправить? Использовал owl-carousel2

Comment: у меня все переключились

Comment: именно вкладки, с маленького изображения на большое

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что переключатель вкладок переключает их на невидимых "клонированых"  слайдах Owl Carusel. Самое простое решение - отключить цикличность карусели, чтобы не создавались "клонированные" слайды.
Или написать свой переключатель, с учетом этой проблемы.

Comment: Отключил цикличность, теперь все работает, большое спасибо!!